# openshift php utf8 encoding

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8

I just deployed my very first php try on openshift platform and even if meta charset utf-8 thing is added to my code, most characters are like '�'.

On localhost everything is ok. I coded the site on notepad++ and encoding there is also set to utf-8.

I tried adding this lines to the template.php but it did no difference as well.

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" value="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<?php ini_set('default_charset', 'utf-8'); ?>
```

So is this because of openshift itself or something that i did wrong ? or any solution ?

Comment: I don't know the openshift platform, but you should check if it doesn't send an encoding in its HTTP header. If so, you can override the encoding with a PHP `header` command.

Comment: header command did not solve it :( is there a way to check if openshift send any header?

Comment: Use any http header reporting service, like the one at [http://web-sniffer.net](http://web-sniffer.net). Give it the URL of your website and look in the results at the Content-Type. If this is only `text/html`, that's fine; if it's something like `text/html; encoding=ISO-8859-1', you'll need to override it (by using the header command in PHP).

Comment: thanks for help :) i've just solved it

Comment: Oh, OK. You never mentioned mysql in the question, so I couldn't know.

Comment: Yes it was my fault :( i have never thought it can arrise from mysql

Answer (score -1):

I am sorry for saying this but the problem is caused by something different than headers or some relevant issue.. the problem was mysql. setting msqli charset to utf 8 solved the issue.

```
$conn->set_charset("utf8");
```